# PlatformException(photo_access_denied, The user did not allow photo access., null, null)

Tags: flutter, image-cropper

If the user didn't allow access to the photos to pick images, I want to ask him another time for the permission or open settings to change the permission, how to do that with image_cropper, how to access the permission and then ask the user again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package to get permission status
https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

```
var status = await Permission.camera.status;
if (status.isDenied) {
  // Here you can open app settings so that the user can give permission
  openAppSettings();
}
```

Comment: but how can we know if the prompt has been shown or not? image_picker shows prompt only the first time but returns the same `isDenied` status is manually storing boolean flag in preferences the only option?